# PHP receives empty $_POST variables from Ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to send form data to a PHP script by using an AJAX call. I'm serializing the form data and sending it as a JSON variable, by a POST method, to a PHP script. Ajax data variable seems correct, but for some reason the PHP $_POST array is empty and I'm having a hard time understanding what I am doing wrong here.

This is my ajax call

```
// AJAX
        var input_data = $('#contact-form').serialize(); 

        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'contact.php',
            type:'POST',
            dataType:'json',//return type from server side function [return it as JSON object]
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: input_data, //Pass the data to the function on server side
            success: function (data) { //Array of data returned from server side function

                $.each(data,function(index){
                    alert(data[index]); // used for debugging, returns 1
                });
            }

        });

        alert("called");
        if(input_data.length < 1)
        {
            alert("empty");
            alert(input_data);
        }
        else
        {
            alert("not empty");
            alert(input_data);
        }
        return false;
```

Form

```
<form class="text-center" id="contact-form" method="POST" action="contact.php">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="msg" name="msg" placeholder="Type your message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="g-recaptcha buffer" data-sitekey="some_key" data-callback="recaptcha_callback"></div>
                        <input type="hidden" class="hiddenRecaptcha required" name="hiddenRecaptcha" id="hiddenRecaptcha">
                    </div>


                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary text-uppercase buffer">Send message</button>
                </form>
```

And finally my contact.php script

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $name;
    $email;
    $msg;

    $nameErr = $emailErr = $msgErr = 0;

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
            $nameErr = 1;
        }
        else {
            $name = $_POST["name"];
            $nameErr = 0;
        }

        if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
            $emailErr = 1;
        }
        else {
            $email = $_POST["email"];
            if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
                $emailErr = 0;
            } else {
                $emailErr = 1;
            }
        }

        if (empty($_POST["msg"]))  {
            $msgErr = 1;
        }
        else {
            $msg = $_POST["msg"];
            $msgErr = 0;
        }

        if($nameErr == 0 && $emailErr == 0 && $msgErr == 0)
        {
            $to = "example@example.com";
            $subject = 'Contact request - site';
            $txt = $_POST['msg'];
            $headers = "From: " . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n";
            mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
            echo json_encode(array("sent"));
        }
        else
        {
            echo json_encode(array($nameErr, $emailErr, $msgErr));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo json_encode(array("post_error"));
    }

?>
```

By running PHP code, the email gets send correctly. When using an Ajax call, $_POST array is empty and it sends back three error codes from the last if statement in PHP code. Also, if there is a better way to acomplish this, I would be more than happy to see an alternative. I appreciate any help, thank you.

EDIT: JSON data

[image: json_data]

Comment: First off, if you're using jQuery, why not just use `$.post()` instead of `$.ajax()`? Second, the $_POST-variables should show up in the PHP-file - do a `var_dump($_POST)` at the start of the PHP-file?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie `$.post` is an alias for `$.ajax` with the type `POST`, there is no need to change something.

Comment: It's not needed, it just is a cleaner method when you already do POST anyway, and you don't need to do any X-HTTP requests. `$.post('contact.php',{ $('#formID').serialize()},function(data) {}}`

Comment: I tried it and it returned an empty array. Calling the PHP script from form action works as expected. I think I'll just rewrite it from scratch tomorrow, it's probably something simple and I just can see it. I'll use jQuery $.post() this time to see how it works.

Comment: Look at your developer console and use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - what do you get back? If only using PHP worked, then your JS is failing then.

Comment: Chrome console returns nothing, error_log from PHP says nothing as well. I added a screenshot of an alert with the json data that's being sent to the PHP script

Comment: I didn't notice (until you posted the json) that you actually send the recaptcha-bit as raw data - then you might actually have to encode the form as `mulitpart/form-data` - but then again, you shouldn't need to send that at all, just check for a proper value, and send true or false (or don't send at all if not true).

Comment: Remove `contentType: "application/json",` from your AJAX call - what you have isn't JSON but a HTTP query string. You should be able to proceed with `$_POST` in your script.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois It is working now. Can you please tell me why and what was the issue? Was it the recaptcha response that was causing it or I did something wrong with making an ajax call? Edit: just saw the comments in the answer, didn't get a notification for some reason

Comment: You told the webserver you are sending JSON, but in fact you were sending a regular HTTP query string - since it was JSON, PHP didn't parse the POST variables into `$_POST`. With the removal of `contentType: "application/json",` jQuery tells the webserver "I send `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data" and makes PHP parse the POST parameters into `$_POST`.

Comment: What would be a right approach if I wanted to send it as a "real" JSON? I'm new to ajax calls and JSON so I'm kinda confused, could you recommend a good read on this topic?

Comment: It's fine as it is. But if you want a real JSON string, use `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: I used it initially and then removed it for some reason. So if I wanted to receive it on PHP side, I would have to decode it and manually parse it (php://input) or there's another way to do it?

Thanks for your help, it really saved my day :) edit: just saw an updated answer, I believe I understand it now

Comment: If you send any other data, you have to read the raw POST data from `php://input` (you can only read it once in PHP < 5.6) and then parse/decode it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `$('#contact-form').serialize()` you make jQuery convert the data from regular fields to a HTTP query string `key=val&key2=val2&...` - but now you set in `$.ajax` that the `contentType` is `application/json`, which makes jQuery set a HTTP header `Content-Type: application/json` to the request. jQuery will not complain that it might be the wrong Content-Type - you should know it the best.

Since the POST-Request has the Content-Type `application/json`, PHP will not parse the HTTP POST data into the superglobal `$_POST`. Instead you have to read the raw POST data from `php://input`.

Your problem is now, that you tell the HTTP POST data is JSON, but it's really not JSON what you send - it's a HTTP query string. Since it's a HTTP query string, you can remove `contentType: "application/json",` from your `$.ajax` call, which will make jQuery set the correct Content-Type header.

jQuery will set the Content-Type header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` - which is the correct Content-Type header for you. Since that is one of the Content-Type PHP parses, the HTTP POST data is now available in the superglobal `$_POST`.

`$_POST` will only be filled on specific Content-Types, namely `multipart/form-data` and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. If the HTTP Content-Type is neither of them, `$_POST` will not be filled and you have to read the RAW POST data from `php://input`.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: So, something along these line would work?

`$str_json = file_get_contents('php://input');
 $str_json = json_decode($str_json);`

Comment: Eh, what? That is blatantly wrong. $_POST receives any type of $_POST-variables, even via AJAX, there is no need to encode it as multipart, as long as you don't have files.

Comment: @Petar-Krešimir If you really send JSON, yes, it should work.

Comment: My point is that it doesn't matter hat content-type you post as - PHP will still receive all the $_POST-variables. Granted, it might matter if the content-type you DO set is a special one, but regular content-type `text/html` will work just fine.

Comment: $_POST **contains the POST-variables** even if you use `text/html` as the content-type. How do I know? I use it on a daily basis when coding websites. And `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` have been deprecated for several PHP-versions now. Sorry: tagging @CharlotteDunois

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie The **request** content-type does matter for `$_POST`, the default content-type for a POST request is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` - `multipart/form-data` if you have files. `text/html` is the regular **response** content-type.